# Angular ngx cookie service doesn`t return few cookie

Tags: angular, cookies, ngx-cookie-service

I use ngx-cookie-service from Angualr to get cookie values, but it doesn`t return few cookie values, [image: This is the image of I have tried]

You might have noticed it retrieves QSTIDDUP and it doesn`t retrieve QSTID

Don`t know what`s the reasons, kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

the cookie is sourced from another domain,  you wouldnt have access to it directly  from within your script.

Comment: but I need it, is there any way

Comment: most probably there are some crazy ways to do this, but the general idea is that it's not possible due to security reasons.   just search a bit on 'accessing cookies from other domains javascript' and you will get the idea :)